# How to identify variable names in an instruction?

Tags: java

I am looking for a solution which will provide me the names of every variable through which the value of password variable passes away. That is, {pass, temp, temp1, var1}

```
class Student{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String password="GOPAL12345";
        Student student=new Student();
        String var1=student.passPassword(password);
        System.out.println("Password is--> "+var1);
    }
    public String passPassword(String pass){
        String temp=pass;
        String temp1=temp;
        return temp1;
    }
}
```

I want this to be done at runtime.

Comment: Are you trying to do this at runtime? or are you trying to parse a .java file and pull out the variable names?

Comment: Try to use Java reflection API.

Comment: user @ Craig: yes exectly

Comment: @rahul You cannot do this at runtime.

Comment: I'm interested in why you need to be able to do this. Please explain your use case.

Comment: you can get all the fields of a class at runtime, but you can't get the variable declared inside a method' also you can't do this 'tracking' of the values.

Comment: @PaulBellora : For checking the information flow in the program or code

Comment: @PaulBellora can i do this using parsing technique, like the compiler identifies the variable names ?

Comment: This is kind of completely useless. When you write the code, you should know why you are assigned objects to variables. You don't just randomly assign objects.

Comment: Have you considered making password into a class?  Then you could just do periodic checks of each variable capable of holding an object of class "Password".  It's a long way round, certainly, but the only one that springs to mind.

Comment: @JDeveloper None of those variables can be accessed via Reflection, and even if they could it wouldn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done. The variable names {pass, temp, temp1, var} aren't present at runtime.

Comment: i am agreed with your answer. but i am just getting this code from the remote PC. and want to check this remote program to check whether it leak information or not.

Comment: @rahul What you want to do has nothing to do with the fact that it's impossible. Also pointless if you ask me.

Comment: user@EJB ok sir, can you provide me any other way to check information leakage during execution of a program or web service ?

Comment: Define 'information leakage'. In fact, define your objective. This is an XY problem. You want to do X, and you think Y is the way to do it, so you are asking about Y, instead of X. Tell us what X is.